# Adding localized js

Tags: javascript, i18n-l10n

I've tried to re-phrase my question in my head a million times, as there seem to be quite a number of approaches and solutions, but finally decided to ask it in a very general way:

What is the best way to localize variables in **external** javascript, such as help hints, tooltips, and such?

Currently I have my js pasted raw into PHP Code, in as many instances as there are languages on the site, and I'm switching the variable set based on:

```
<?php
  global $language;
  $lang = $language->language;
?>
```

but I strongly dislike having a gazillion of copies of same text throughout the site. This is good for testing, but for production I want just one javascript file which I could call with parameters, something like:

```
<script src="myscript.js?hl=<?php print $lang?>"><script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal has an in-built mechanism to handle this sort of thing, the `Drupal.settings` javascript variable you'll see in the source code for any Drupal site.

Used in conjunction with [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js) in your PHP code you can easily pass variables to javascript, which will be available in your custom script files.

For example in a custom module you could add a settings variable like this:

```
global $language;
$mySettings = array('language' => $language->language);

drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $mySettings), 'setting');
```

Then in your javascript file you can pick up that variable like this:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var language = Drupal.settings.mymodule.language;
    if (language == 'en') {
      // etc
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Using this method your template code can be a lot cleaner and you don't need to worry about passing URL variables to the javascript file, or building up the javascript in PHP any more.

Comment: Wonderful concept, even though it requires writing a module ;-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Artur No probs :) I'm pretty sure you could do this at the theme level, say in `hook_preprocess_page()` in the template.php file, so you wouldn't necessarily have to write a module

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking localization, there's also a t() version of Javascript in the form of Drupal.t(), e.g.

```
   $("#div").text(Drupal.t('Mouseover tooltip'));
```

Your script will need to be added by drupal_add_js().

See http://drupal.the-aim.be/drupal-translate-jquery for a bit more on it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the language in a setting or parsing the URL you can also use this code to get the actual language of the site:

```
var lang = $('html').attr('lang');
```

This works as all themes should render (at least) this info:

```
<html class="" lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
```

References:

[JAVASCRIPT get current language!!!](https://www.drupal.org/node/575842)